# FDT: Could not resolve variable (may be an XML element name)

Tags: actionscript-3, fdt

I'm getting some warning signs in FDT in a couple of lines of code that access values in the app descriptor, like this:

```
var appDescriptor:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
var ns:Namespace = appDescriptor.namespace();
var appId:String = appDescriptor.ns::id[0];
var appVersion:String = appDescriptor.ns::versionNumber[0];
```

Those lines work fine, but FDT underlines "id" and "versionNumber", and issues the warning "Could not resolve variable (may be an XML element name)".

Is there a way to get rid of that warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of, you can use this snippet:

```
/*FDT_IGNORE*/
// your code
/*FDT_IGNORE*/
```

to have FDT ignore the code therein. Another option is to try these settings. Otherwise try different parser / error settings to see what happens.

[Preferences http://dl.dropbox.com/u/154189/web/never/Preferences.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/154189/web/never/Preferences.png)

Comment: Sorry, but that /*FDT_IGNORE*/ tag doesn't work as intended. That doesn't just make FDT ignore warnings/errors. It also makes FDT ignore the whole line, as if it didn't exist at all! So if I put those comment tags around that code, those variables are not available in subsequent lines and FDT then underlines in red every call to appId, since it thinks it wasn't declared. So this is worse than not adding that tag, since now I get errors instead of just warnings. The second tip might be more like what I want, but I'd prefer not having to disable that.

Comment: Well, I've managed to make FDT ignore lines without generating extra errors.
This is what I've done:

var appId:String, appVersion:String;

/*FDT_IGNORE*/
appId = appDescriptor.ns::id[0];
appVersion = appDescriptor.ns::versionNumber[0];
/*FDT_IGNORE*/

So instead of assigning the value in the same line, I first declare the variables and then I make FDT ignore the assigning lines, so FDT still knows those variables are declared.

Thanks for the tip!

PS: Why does StackOverflow strip all newlines from comments? This is annoying to read like this!